# Can I disable the blue highlighting in YUI menus on Safari and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, yui, yui-menu

I'm getting a sort of glow-y blueish rollover highlighting of my YUI menu items when I'm in Safari and Chrome (but not Firefox).  Cool though this is, it's not consistent with the rest of my site's highlighting, and I'd like to disable it.  I'm guessing this is a webkit css property, but, if it is, haven't found the one(s) that control it. Can anyone point me to the right place?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this CSS rule with the appropiate selector:

```
outline-width:0;
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that the blueish outline is an accessibility feature; ideally it should be replaced with something else, not just removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple tweak instead of this would be to use something like this:

```
 outline-style:none;
```

you can apply this to something like this...

```
 #element:focus {
     outline-style:none;
 }
```